# Why isn't my email showing up as registered with Wordpress anymore?

Tags: wp-admin

I can't login to my blog anymore...I tried requesting a new password, but it is telling me that my email is not one that is registered. I definitely have an account and a blog, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use phpMyAdmin to reset both your email address and your password.

1. Open the `wp_users` table.
2. Edit the row with your username.
3. Update your email address as needed. If it's set to an address you're unfamiliar with, as in your blog may have been hacked, it may be best to stop here and get professional help so that you don't just get re-hacked. At the very least, install a security plugin like Wordfence and contact your host for any help they can give. If instead you're like me and you just didn't remember which one of your plethora of email addresses you used, jot down a note of which email you used.
4. In the `user_pass` field, first change the function to MD5 - this is what encrypts the password and makes it work - and type in whatever password you want to use.

Once you complete this update, you should be able to log in as usual.